# House price prediction method using Time Series

Tags: multiple-regression

Courses mainly teach house prices prediction with multiple linear regression. Indeed the one I did on coursera and that makes sense to me.

I note that some feel time series is also a suitable method. I am not clear as to why this could be so. Simply because there is no regular notion of selling a house, it can be at any time.

Looking for a clarification.

Comment: https://autobox.com/pdfs/regvsbox-old.pdf which I wrote many moons ago might be useful to you as it compares ols regression ( as you know it ) and time series methods AND their integration into one equation .

Comment: I should have stated that if you have equally spaced  data in time  then my comment might be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time series: So, I believe you mention a different approach.

The data that people use in the examples you mention in coursera is based on the following assumption: The data was collected in the same date and you have many different features associated with the data. **So the question here is to asssociate the price of a house with the features of the house.**

However, your question may be different. **You may want to study the prices of the same house (or an average house or many different houses like a panel) will be smaller or larger in the future.**  So the problem here is not to associate the features to the house, but to know how some economic variables may affect the house. For instance, in times of low economic activity (low gdp) people do not have money and, therefore, less houses are sold. Since less houses are sold, the prices of an average house also falls. Usually economists are interested in this kind of problems. So depending on your data you may use a time series model or dynamic panel data. Usually, you have a structure that the price of the house today depends on the price of the same (or a similar) house in the past, since the characteristics are the same.

Comment: Answer too general I feel. But I am not the expert.

Comment: So, what you are saying, having read your profile, is that you agree with me linear regression is not so good for house price predictions in basic form. Seems you need an 'inflationary' component.

Comment: Like everything in economics, @thebluephantom it depends on your question. What do you want to know. For instance, zillow uses models that asssociate the price of the houses with their features. However, it you want to know the impact of the economic variables, you will need something else.

Comment: That's a little easy going. Anyway. As it so happens due to corona I am now running a kaggle example of multivariate regression for this and note that the data has year sold but it is not a significant contributor to the regression formula. Seems odd to me as I think it would always have something to do with it. Anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. You have to build the data you need to anwer the question. It is not that I have data and I can answer this question. It is the opposite. First, you have to formulate the important research question. Then, you try to build your data. Maybe you are not able to build the original data you want. So, maybe you can change a little bit your question to be able to answer it with the data you have in hand. Furthermore, depend on your intersting is inference or prediction, the choices of the variables are carried on using very different procedures.

Comment: We will leave it at that. I am also university educated and have a few clues.

Answer (score 0):

Time series can be useful to see how different variables change with time. While predicting the house prices, the time series can be useful to analyse the changes in prices with respect to zipcode, like to provide the best zip codes to invest in for a real estate developer looking for a place to develop a new apartment building.

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: +1 I do not understand the -1 that someone gave to you. It is also correct your answer.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan Thanks, man. But I can't see -1 on it.

Comment: There was a -1. With +1 that I gave to you you got zero that is what you see now.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan Ahh okay, Thanks, buddy.

Comment: In stackoverflow if you have a privilege of a 1000 (I think) you can see all point without aggregation, but we do not have this privilege here.

Comment: I saw no -1 afaik.

Comment: Not sure I am getting the idea.

Comment: @thebluephantom There is no -1 as DanielTheRocketMan gave +1 and now it is zero.

Comment: Okay Let me give you another example, time series is useful when your data is change with time, in case of house price prediction, it can change with year, market conditions and many more factors that change with time. In these kinds of scenarios, the time series is helpful. You might find this helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264196/is-house-price-prediction-a-regression-or-a-time-series-problem

Comment: But mys statement is till true, I saw no -1...

Comment: But I get the coursera example, I am just wondering how the timeseries can be applicable given that a house selling date is not really predicatble.

Comment: @thebluephantom Sorry, I didn't follow you on that, I am assuming you don't have to predict the selling date, rather you have to use the selling date to predict the price. Which Coursera course are you referring to?  The one by Andrew Ng?

Comment: @thebluephantom Yes correct there is no -1, I am a newbie here, if you find this answer useful, your upvote would really motivate me to answer more question.